# Vlookup and Sumif?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

I am trying to do a vlookup that pulls the accurate cell phone checks, per "status" (All Star, noob, etc.) into my coffee beans table.

I figured the VLookup would get me there in combination with sumif (perhaps) ...went down the Index match route but don't think thats what I need.

Any thoughts or recommendations would be extremely helpful and most appreciated. I am not really sure what I need to be reading to get me what I need.

The Vlookup I am using is

=VLOOKUP(A2:A16,CellChecks,3,0)

However it returns, for example, 1495 Cell Phone Checks for All Stars for 2012-11-04 (which is correct) but it again returns 1495 for noobs (cell D3)

Its just matching the date and I need to know how to match with the Status so that in cell D3 the value of '12' is returned instead of the current 1495 being displayed.

I hope all of this is clear.

[image]

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. You have to give more details about what you are trying to achieve, the code you have produced and how it fails by describing the erroneous behavior or/and providing error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. In cell D2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$20:$A$34=$A1)*($B$20:$B$34=$B1)*$C$20:$C$34)
```